# Stop Android Studio from hiding/shortening code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is what I see in Android Studio:
[image]

While this is actually the [real code](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/ui/email/CheckEmailHandler.java#L51):

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode != RequestCodes.CRED_HINT || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) { return; }

    setResult(Resource.<User>forLoading());
    final Credential credential = data.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY);
    final String email = credential.getId();
    ProviderUtils.fetchTopProvider(getAuth(), getArguments(), email)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        setResult(Resource.forSuccess(new User.Builder(task.getResult(), email)
                                .setName(credential.getName())
                                .setPhotoUri(credential.getProfilePictureUri())
                                .build()));
                    } else {
                        setResult(Resource.<User>forFailure(task.getException()));
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

How can I stop Anroid Studio from doing this? And by which rules at all does Android Studio this shortening?

Answer (score 4):

Cant close this as a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/q/644438/140879) so I'll just put the answer here (edited) for future reference:

You can disable *code folding* in the *Settings* menu of Android Studio, un-tick the *"Closures"* and *"Generic constructor and method parameters"* boxes under ***Editor → General → Code Folding***:

[image]

As for the reason the screenshot has the answer, but its set to fold *"Closures"* which are anonymous inner classes with 1 method as well as *"Generic constructor and method parameters"*.